# The difference between PopupMenuItem Click and MouseOver

Tags: delphi, contextmenu, delphi-2007

When a Menu Item has a sub Menu hovering the mouse expands the sub-menu it fires a click event.

Is there any difference between this click event and if the user actually clicks?

I'm using a TPopupMenu as dropdown property of a cxButton.

**EDIT**
Delphi 2007

Comment: and which version of Delphi you're using ?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want to know one way or the other? The sub-menu should expand in both cases?

Comment: @Marjan - I was mimicking a tree structure with the menu system where not only the leaf nodes were selectable, so it need to expand when hovered but "Selected" when clicked.  I think I'll just redesign the GUI for that screen to something more sensible now I have this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this will work with D2007; it does in D7. Can you try the following?

```
type
  THackPopupList = class(TPopupList)
  private
    FActuallyClicked: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  public
    property ActuallyClicked: Boolean read FActuallyClicked;
  end;

{ THackPopupList }

procedure THackPopupList.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  FActuallyClicked := Message.Msg = WM_COMMAND;
  inherited WndProc(Message);
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.MenuFileOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
var 
  ActuallyClicked: Boolean;
begin
  ActuallyClicked := THackPopupList(PopupList).ActuallyClicked;
  ...
end;

initialization
  PopupList.Free;
  PopupList := THackPopupList.Create;

end.
```

Explanation: The OnClick which is triggered by a hover is initiated by a WM_INITMENUPOPUP, but the OnClick which is triggered by a mouse click is initiated by this WM_COMMAND.

This depends on Menus.pas already having been initialized. But as I understand from [Delphi unit initialization order](http://www.saunalahti.fi/janij/blog/2006-04.html), that is guaranteed even if you put this code in an auxiliary unit.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. If the user clicks the item or hover it, the same *OnClick* event is fired.
I've checked this for *Delphi 2009*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the user actually clicks a MenuItem with sub menu items, the OnClick event is *not* fired. So the distinction is made by:

```
procedure TForm1.MenuFileOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ActuallyClicked: Boolean;
begin
  ActuallyCLicked := TMenuItem(Sender).Count = 0;
end;
```

And if the menu item has a linked action:

```
procedure TForm1.FileOpenExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  ActuallyClicked: Boolean;
begin
  if Sender is TBasicAction then
    Sender := TBasicAction(Sender).ActionComponent;
  ActuallyCLicked := TMenuItem(Sender).Count = 0;
end;
```

Comment: If the user clicks the item or hover it; the same `TMenuItem.Click` method is called (and from this method `OnClick` event fires up) so they are same. As you pointed here you can distinguish if the menu item has any subitem but you can't find out if the user clicks or just hover.

Comment: Yes you can: If there is a sub menu, clicking the menu item will not result in a OnClick event. If there is no sub menu, hovering the menu item will not result in a OnClick event.

Comment: No you can't. We are talking about situation when you have item with some subitem(s); and there is no difference between OnClick fired from hover or the real click. At least in D2009.

Comment: Ok, then this behaviour is changed somewhere after D7.