# Delphi TMenuItem OnClick not working if menu has sub items

Tags: delphi, winapi

It appears `Onclick` events are not processed for menu items that have sub-items.

I realize I could create a leaf item which users could use instead, but I would like to have my menu folders respond to `OnClick` (in my case to "launch" all sub-items)

Is there any way around this limitation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Menu items that have sub-items do indeed fire `OnClick` events. But they fire when the sub-menu opens rather than when you click on the parent menu item.

I'm pretty sure you don't want to invoke all sub-items when that happens. The `OnClick` event for a parent menu fires whenever the sub-menu is opened. Either when you click on the parent menu item, hover over it, or press the right arrow key when the menu item is selected via the keyboard.

So, the `OnClick` event for a parent menu corresponds to opening the sub-menu. Invoking all the child menu item actions when the sub-menu is opened goes against all standard expected UI behaviour. What you should do is add another sub-item that can be used to invoke all actions. Don't go against the platform standard UI unless there are no sane alternatives.

Comment: For my specific system tray launcher application where the user explicitly will have to assign an on-click action on the menu items... I am hoping it will be okay what I am planning... Anyhow, I am looking into various poential solutions right now. Will report back incase anyone interestered. (Could look like quite a bit of hassle though.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328497/the-difference-between-popupmenuitem-click-and-mouseover does seem helpful. However, it seems like normal clicks do not trigger any message on menu items with sub-items, but I will try investigate this further.

Comment: For items with submenus you get `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP`. I ascertained this using Spy++. You'd have to decode the message pos to work out whether or not the click was on your special menu item. You'd also need to look out for those that use keyboard to access your menu. Obviously it's possible to do what you are asking to do, but you really should think very very hard about making such a bizarre and counter-intuitive UI. There's a very good alternative which you yourself have already identified. You should do that.

Comment: Well, they do not fire for me in my inherited PopupList.WndProc(var Message: TMessage); Only WM_COMMAND does (and not when clicking items with subfolder.) Oh well. Maybe because it is a system tray menu. Will rettturn if I have more info later.